# Removing divs embedded within a div in an html document using PyQuery

Tags: python

Using PyQuery, I'd like to get a div of a particular class, remove all divs and javascript embedded within that main div, and obtain the text contents of what remains in the main div. So far, here is my code:

```
pq = pyquery(urllib2.urlopen(source_url).read())
# remove embedded divs and javascript here
content = pq('.main_div').text()
```

What's the best way to go about removing the divs embedded within the main div?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, figured it out. Here's one way to do it:

```
pq = pyquery(urllib2.urlopen(source_url).read())('.main_div')
pq('div').remove()
pq('script').remove()
content = pq.text()
```